# Accessing tuple item from discriminated union

Tags: f#

I have type called type x and it has following members in the form of discriminated union

```
type Info= Empty | Value of int | Pair of (int * int)
```

I have a function which takes two arguments and filter the list according to comparisons made by n. I cannot figure out the last part. How can I compare each value of Pair with my n value in that function?

```
let filterInfo (n:int) (xs:Info list) = xs |>  List.filter (fun (x) -> x <> Empty && x > Value n && // )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a function that compares a single `Info` object by using pattern matching. Something like this should suffice:

```
let compareInfo (n:int) (info:Info) =
        match info with
        | Empty -> false
        | Value x -> n > x
        | Pair (a, b) -> ...
```

You can call it by curring `n` from your filter call:

```
let filterInfo (n:int) (xs:Info list) = xs |>  List.filter (compareInfo n)
```

Comment: Is it possible to do it without creating any other function?

Comment: You need to create a function, named or anonymous. If you want an anonymous function, try:
``fun n -> function Empty -> false | Value x -> n > x | Pair (a, b) -> ...``

Comment: Should i try something like that Pair (a, b) -> n>a && n>b  in the last part? I am really confused about it

Comment: Pattern matching "unwraps" the values that each match contains, allowing you to compare them. So yes, if `n>a && n>b` suits your business need, then it's probably the right thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up adding a read-only property that pattern-matches on `this`:

```
type Thing =
    | Sphere of Sphere * Surface
    | Plane of Plane * Surface

    member this.surface =
        match this with
        | Sphere(_, surface) -> surface
        | Plane(_, surface) -> surface
```